# Calculations with FX

Tags: java, validation, calculator, javafx

There have been a lot of calculators lately. It seems like [this](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5174/april-2015-community-challenge) community challenge all over again, I didn't make a [proper](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88525/permutation-and-combination-calculator) one then, so I'm joining the calculatrain now.

Building from the lessons learned from a preceding [far simpler](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/83477/lambdas-will-guide-you-home-css-will-ignite-your-code-java-ill-try-to-fx-you) calculator.

[image: application screenshot]

The goal was to encompass corner cases that are otherwise easy to miss. I'd like pinpoint whether I've missed anything and whether I'm doing something inefficiently that should/could be done in a cleaner way.

I'm also concerned about names and readability, I want to make this easy to follow and understand, despite it being a solo venture, the purpose is practice, and if CR has taught me anything it's that that is crucial.

**Calculator.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Calculator extends Application {
    static Operator currentOperator;
    static boolean operatorSelected;
    static boolean resultDisplayed;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();

        TextField auxiliary = new TextField();
        auxiliary.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 15; -fx-text-fill: gray");
        auxiliary.setMaxWidth(415); // 415 = total width, including margins of buttons
        auxiliary.setEditable(false);

        TextField result = new TextField();
        result.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 40");
        result.setMaxWidth(415); 
        result.setEditable(false);

        VBox resultLayout = new VBox();
        resultLayout.getChildren().addAll(auxiliary, result);
        layout.setTop(resultLayout);


        GridPane buttonLayout = new GridPane();
        buttonLayout.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 0));
        buttonLayout.setHgap(5);
        buttonLayout.setVgap(5);
        layout.setCenter(buttonLayout);

        Button backButton = new Button("\u2190");
        backButton.setMinSize(100, 100);
        backButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            String currentText = result.getText();
            if (!currentText.isEmpty() && !resultDisplayed){
                result.setText(currentText.substring(0, currentText.length() - 1));
            }
        });
        buttonLayout.add(backButton, 2, 0);

        Button clearButton = new Button("Clear");
        clearButton.setMinSize(200, 100);
        clearButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            result.clear();
            auxiliary.clear();
            operatorSelected = false;
        });
        GridPane.setColumnSpan(clearButton, 2); 
        buttonLayout.add(clearButton, 0, 0);

        Button[] numberButtons = new Button[10];
        for (int i = 3, target = 1; i >= 1; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
                String number = Integer.toString(target);

                numberButtons[target] = new Button(number);
                numberButtons[target].setMinSize(100, 100);
                numberButtons[target].setOnAction(e -> {
                    if (resultDisplayed) {
                        result.setText(number);
                        resultDisplayed = false;
                    } else {
                        result.appendText(number);
                    }

                    operatorSelected = false;
                });
                buttonLayout.add(numberButtons[target++], j, i);
            }   
        }

        numberButtons[0] = new Button("0");
        numberButtons[0].setMinSize(200, 100);
        numberButtons[0].setOnAction(e -> {
            if (!result.getText().isEmpty() && !resultDisplayed) {
                result.appendText("0");
                operatorSelected = false;
            }
        });
        GridPane.setColumnSpan(numberButtons[0], 2);
        buttonLayout.add(numberButtons[0], 0, 4);


        Button decimalButton = new Button(".");
        decimalButton.setMinSize(100, 100);
        decimalButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (result.getText().indexOf('.') == -1) {
                result.appendText(".");
            }
        });
        buttonLayout.add(decimalButton, 2, 4);

        for (Operator op : Operator.values()) {
            String symbol = op.toString();

            Button button = new Button(symbol);
            button.setMinSize(100, 100);
            button.setStyle("-fx-color: orange");
            button.setOnAction(e -> {
                if (auxiliary.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    auxiliary.setText(result.getText().isEmpty() ? "0" : acquireValue(result.getText()));
                    auxiliary.appendText(" " + symbol);
                    currentOperator = op;
                    resultDisplayed = true;
                    operatorSelected = true;
                } else if (operatorSelected) {
                    currentOperator = op;
                    int end = auxiliary.getText().length();
                    auxiliary.replaceText(end - 1, end,  symbol);
                } else {
                    auxiliary.setText(calculate(currentOperator, result, auxiliary) + " " + symbol);
                    result.clear();
                    currentOperator = op;
                    resultDisplayed = true;
                    operatorSelected = true;
                }
            });
            buttonLayout.addColumn(3, button);
        }

        Button equalsButton = new Button("=");
        equalsButton.setStyle("-fx-color: orange");
        equalsButton.setMinSize(100, 100);
        equalsButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (!auxiliary.getText().isEmpty()) {
                result.setText(
                    calculate(currentOperator, result, auxiliary)
                );
                resultDisplayed = true;
                operatorSelected = false;
                auxiliary.clear();
            }
        });
        buttonLayout.addColumn(3, equalsButton);
        equalsButton.setDefaultButton(true);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("Calculator.css");

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.setTitle("Legato's Calculator");
        stage.show();
    }

    private static String calculate(Operator op, TextField main, TextField auxiliary) {
        double val1 = Double.parseDouble(auxiliary.getText().replaceAll("[^\\.0-9]", ""));
        double val2 = Double.parseDouble(main.getText());

        if (val2 == 0 && op == Operator.DIVIDE) {
            return "Cannot divide by 0";
        }

        double result = op.compute(val1, val2);
        return toCalculatorString(result);
    }

    private static String acquireValue(String val) {
        double result = Double.parseDouble(val);
        return toCalculatorString(result);
    }

    private static String removeDecimalTrailingZeroes(String s) {
        return s.indexOf(".") < 0 ? s : s.replaceAll("0*$", "").replaceAll("\\.$", "");
    }

    private static String toCalculatorString(double input) {
        return input == (int)input ? 
            Integer.toString((int)input) : removeDecimalTrailingZeroes(String.format("%.6f", input));
    }
}
```

**Operator.java**

```
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;

public enum Operator {
    DIVIDE("\u00F7", (x, y) -> x / y),
    MULTIPLY("x", (x, y) -> x * y),
    SUBTRACT("-", (x, y) -> x - y),
    ADD("+", (x, y) -> x + y);

    private final String symbol;
    private final BinaryOperator<Double> equation;


    Operator(String symbol, BinaryOperator<Double> equation) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.equation = equation;
    }

    public double compute(double alpha, double beta) {
        return equation.apply(alpha, beta);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return symbol;
    }
}
```

**Calculator.css**

```
 .text-field {
    -fx-text-box-border: transparent;
    -fx-background-color: -fx-control-inner-background;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-padding: 1 3 1 3;
}


.text-field:focused {
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
}
```

Feel free to [download](https://github.com/Javaliant/NewCalculator/blob/master/Calculator.jar?raw=true) and run it. Requires **JRE 8**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way around it, but `start()` is too lengthy... you should consider breaking it down. For example, you can consolidate your UI elements in the following manner:

- Auxillary and main text fields
- The `Clear` and "backspace" buttons
- The numeric and dot buttons
- The operator buttons

Then, `start()` will only have four such method calls, which can make its readability much better.

As for the `Operator` enum, you may want to consider using [`DoubleBinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/DoubleBinaryOperator.html) instead of `BinaryOperator<Double>` to avoid the auto-boxing.